# Geany : Build Execute python ignoring setting

Tags: python, geany

With Build/Set Build Commands/Execute Commands

Two items:

```
 1. Execute (the installed) 
 2. Python3 (custom)
```

Both fields set to :

```
 /usr/bin/python3 -i "%f"
```

With otherwise working python file in the current window, pressing F5 or Selecting Build.Python3 has the same result:

Terminal window opens to file directory. No activity.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the Edit/Preferences/Tools/Terminal field. I changed

```
 mate-terminal
```

to

```
 mate-terminal -e "/bin/sh %c"
```

Now all is well.